# Removing an arrayList object Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this method I use to remove a Book from the SetOfBooks class. I tried looping through and delete too, and googled too. This does not delete the Book object I'm passing and returns false,I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. I wanted the method to remove the given object from the list.
Please help. Thankyou

The following is the code of the where I call the removebook() method.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: cannot delete the object I pass as the parameter

Comment: I suspect you mean `public class SetOfBooks extends Vector<Book> {`, not `public class SetOfBooks<Book> extends Vector<Book> {`. In the latter case, `Book` is a type variable, not the `Book` class.

Comment: I think that you will need to create and post a decent [mcve] to get a decent answer. Side issue: have you overridden equals and hashCode properly in your Book class?

Comment: `remove` is using `indexOf` to locate position of element, but `indexOf` is using `equals` method to determine if searched object is same as object which it is currently *looking at*. Problem is that if you don't override `equals` method in your Book it will be inherited from its superclass, which in your case is Object, and implementation used there simply uses `==` to see if two references are equal, not if two objects represent same state.

Comment: Yes, I was right -- you do not override those two key methods, equals and hashCode. Please read up on and then fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably did not override the `equals` (and `hashcode`) methods in your `Book` class.

Without overriding `equals` only the exact same object will be removed from a collection using `remove`.

Comment: When overriding `equals` and `hashCode` according to their contracts take special care for potentially mutable fields like `borrower`. With implementations for these methods autogenerated from your IDE all of those fields are included. If you have e.g. one place in code where you don't know the borrower and construct a book object in order to find or remove the "real" book which actually has a borrower this also won't work.